# Sticky element inside a grid layout is not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have a sticky table inside a grid element. This works both in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. Here is a simplified test case out of the existing markup I have. Looking for a solution that works on all browsers without too many changes to the existing markup.

```
        <div style="display: grid;grid-template-columns: 30px 1fr;column-gap: 5px;">
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <div style="position: relative;overflow: scroll;height:200px;">
                    <div style="position: absolute;background-color: transparent;top: 0;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;pointer-events: none;height:2000px;"></div>
                    <table style="position:sticky;top:100;min-width:50%;width:100%;">
                        <tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I change "display: grid" to "display: block" everything works in Safari as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue based on the solution provided at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20307

Essentially, I was trying to have two siblings one the table and another a large virtual div and have the table sticky. This works in chrome and firefox with any parent div having flex or grid. In safari it doesn't work with parent being flex or grid. But the bootstrap issue mentioned above suggested providing space to the element to float and that made me change the markup to include the table inside the other virtual sibling I originally had. With this change, it works in Safari as well.